# transfer live prestashop web to localhost and xampp?

Tags: php, xampp, prestashop-1.6

I have cloned a whole online website built with prestashop by FTP and hosted it on a XAMPP. I have downloaded the SQL dump and imported it locally with phpMyAdmin. I have changed the conf files to use the local database.

When I go to localhost/myProject it redirects me to the website url. Why is that ? is there another configuration setting to edit? I have already looked in the conf table in database and domain URL was already set to "localhost", even on the online version.

I found a reference to the website in table "ps_shop_url". I changed its values to localhost, now when I go to localhost it tells me "this page has an infinite redirection loop"

Answer (score 0):

change the you site url to localhost in database.sql file as below:
 Change **www.yourdomain.com** to **localhost** & make sure you have putted your site htdocs directory...

Answer (score 0):

Can you show entry that you have made in ps_shop_url table.

Physical url should be /prestashop1606/ for localhost/prestashop1606/